# What is the right way to generate long sequence using PyTorch-Transformers?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model

I am trying to generate a long sequence of text using PyTorch-Transformers from a sample text. I am following [this tutorial](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2019/07/pytorch-transformers-nlp-python/) for this purpose. Because the original article only predicts one word from a given text, I modified that script to generate long sequence instead of one. This is the modified part of the code

```
# Encode a text inputs
text = """An examination can be defined as a detailed inspection or analysis
 of an object or person. For example, an engineer will examine a structure,
  like a bridge, to see if it is safe. A doctor may conduct"""

indexed_tokens = tokenizer.encode(text)

# Convert indexed tokens in a PyTorch tensor
tokens_tensor = torch.tensor([indexed_tokens])
seq_len = tokens_tensor.shape[1]
tokens_tensor = tokens_tensor.to('cuda')


with torch.no_grad():
    for i in range(50):
        outputs = model(tokens_tensor[:,-seq_len:])
        predictions = outputs[0]
        predicted_index = torch.argmax(predictions[0, -1, :])
        tokens_tensor = torch.cat((tokens_tensor,predicted_index.reshape(1,1)),1)


pred = tokens_tensor.detach().cpu().numpy().tolist()
predicted_text = tokenizer.decode(pred[0])
print(predicted_text)
```

Output

> An examination can be defined as a detailed inspection or analysis
> of an object or person. For example, an engineer will examine a
> structure,   like a bridge, to see if it is safe. A doctor may conduct
> an examination of a patient's body to see if it is safe.
>
> The doctor may also examine a patient's body to see if it is safe. A
> doctor may conduct an examination of a patient's body to see if it is
> safe.

As you can see the generated text does not generates any unique text sequence but it generates the same sentence over and over again with minor changes.

How should we create long sequence using  PyTorch-Transformers?

Comment: Please chack some o the parameters of the [generate method](https://huggingface.co/transformers/v4.5.1/main_classes/model.html#transformers.generation_utils.GenerationMixin.generate) (e.g.: `repetition_penalty`, `temperature`, `length_penalty`).

Answer (score 0):

There is usually no such thing as generating a complete sentence or complete text once. There were some research approaches on that but almost all of the state-of-the-art models generate a text word by word. The generated word at time t-1 is then used as input (together with other already generated or given words) while generating the next word at time t. So, it is normal that it generates word by word. I do not understand what you mean by this.

Which model are you using?